# How to create json dynamically?

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

I need to create a json dynamically using class. For example following is my json `"{'createdDate':['2019-07-20T05:53:28','2019-07-20T05:53:28']}"`. The class i need is

```
public class Json
{
  public string Key {get;set;}
  public List<string> value {get;set;}
}
```

Creating object and assigning value

```
var JsonObj = new Json();
JsonObj.key = "createdDate";
JsonObj.Add("2019-07-20T05:53:28");
JsonObj.Add("2019-07-20T05:53:28");
```

The above class is for single key value pair. But the problem is the key and values are dynamic.may be the key value pairs single or multiple. How can i solve the problem. can anyone try to help me.

Comment: Can you show some sample dynamic values? Or expected result?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Prashant Pimpale.The dynamic value may like this {"createdDate":["2019-07-20T05:53:28","2019-07-20T05:53:28"],"id":["1","2"],"name":["name1","name2"],...}

Comment: You can use below way :  
`dynamic stuff1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring)`

No need of class and You access the element by the json path .

Comment: If you already have the class declaration that produces the JSON you need, why do you need a more dynamic solution? Please post a description and example of what your current solution doesn't support. You mention "key value pairs single or multiple", can you show an example of the expected output your current class doesn't support?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem starts with your nomenclature.  Your class is not json, it's merely a list with a name.   All you need to do is create your named list, and then serialise it to json using, for example, Newtonsoft.Json.   Here's a bit of code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            NamedList list = new NamedList();
            list.Key = "createdDate";
            list.Value.Add( "2019-07-20T05:53:28" );
            list.Value.Add( "2019-07-20T05:53:29" );

            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( list );
        }
    }

    public class NamedList
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public List<string> Value { get; set; }= new List<string>();
    }
}
```